Use NAT for only outgoing traffic, and keep public IPs of ECS instances open for inbound traffic
I have a particular usecase where I need to connect via a longer running websocket connection to a port on dynamically created ECS instances, and so I need the ECS instances to have public IPs and be in a public subnet.
However, the instances also make other outgoing network calls to an external service, and I want to whitelist the IP CIDR block in that external service to the IPs of my ECS tasks.
So I wanted to create a NAT gateway for that to have an elastic IP, but the issue with that is that I then can't establish that inbound websocket connection directly to the ECS instances anymore since there's now one static IP for all of them.
Is there a way to get around this at all in AWS? I want the outgoing connections to be under the shared elastic IP, but for incoming connections to be able to go directly to the ECS task public IPs.

Did you consider running your containers behind an Application Load Balancer(ALB)? ALB supports WebSocket protocol and will handle ongoing traffic. It will allow you to run the containers in the private subnet using NAT for outgoing requests.

I see, yeah that should work then as long as I use sticky sessions on the ALB since the ECS instance will maintain and accumulate state specific to the client that created it. I was just curious if there was a different solution without setting up an ALB, but that might be best. Thanks!

I don't think Amazon has an out-of-the-box solution that would be the better alternative. If the external APIs you call don't have static IPs you won't be able to route only this traffic through the NAT. The solution that could work is an  HTTP(Level 7) proxy server for outgoing requests, but it would require changes in the app code\settings and some efforts to make it reliable\scalable.
